# How do I get the node ID from the URL?

Tags: 7, uri

So far, I came across these 3 functions in Drupal 7, but I am not really sure what the difference between them is, and which is more appropriated to get the node ID in a block preprocess function.

- [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)
- [`menu_get_item()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)
- [`drupal_lookup_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7)

Can you give me any insight?

Comment: Are you doing this in node.tpl.php or something like that? If yes, you could use $node->nid.

Comment: No i am doing this in a block preprocess function, though the block does get printed on the node page.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> I am not really sure what the difference between them is

- [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) returns the object associated with the page currently shown. If the code is executed when Drupal is showing the page example.com/node/1, then `menu_get_object()` will return the node object for the node whose ID is 1; if the page being shown is example.com/user/1, then `menu_get_object('user')` will return the user object for the user whose ID is 1.
- [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) returns an array containing an index for each field contained in the "menu_router" table. This includes:

  - path: the current path of the menu callback
  - load_functions: an array of function names (like `node_load`) to be called to load an object corresponding to a part of the current path
  - access_callback: the callback that checks if the currently logged in user has access to the menu item
  - page_callback: the name of the function that renders the page
  - title: the title for the page associated to the menu item
- [drupal_lookup_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7) is the function that returns you the internal path associated with the alias passed as argument. If "homepage" is the alias associated to example.com/node/1, then `drupal_lookup_path("homepage")` will return `"node/1"`. Path aliases can be associated to any internal paths, not only to node paths.

> and which is more appropriated to get the node ID in a block preprocess function.

If all you want to get is the node ID of the node currently shown, then you just need to use the following code:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
}
```

If you need to get the node object, then you can use the following code:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Use the node object.
}
```

Of those snippets, the second is better, as it returns the correct node object for internal paths such as node/1/revisions/3/view.

Keep in mind that some preprocess functions, such as the ones for the page, or the node, have already a `$variables['node']`. This means that in those cases, you just need to use the following snippet in your preprocess function, without worrying about which function to use.

```
if (isset($variables['node'])) {
  // Check the node ID or other properties.
}
```

For other preprocess functions, check the documentation to see if there is any variable containing the node object. For example, that is the case for [`template_preprocess_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7) which makes `$variables['node']` available to the preprocess functions for comments.

Answer (score 8):

How it's done in Drupal Core's [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7):

Line 2267 of [theme.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/7) and onwards:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
}
```

template_preprocess_page uses [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7). After that it's just a matter of checking if the node is defined and getting $node->nid.

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 8, you can get url arguments based on what's in the routing.

To get the id alone:

```
$nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
```

If you plan to load the node object, you can simply get it this way:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

To find the parameter names, you can use:

```
$possible_parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing you have to be careful of is path alias.

`drupal_get_normal_path($path)`

to get the current path use the system variable `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

(If you are on the node page you can call `$node->uri['path']`,  this will return a non-alias path. Then again if you are on the node page, you can just use `$node->nid`.)

this will return node/XXXX

so try something like

```
  $node_path = explode('/', drupal_get_normal_path($path));
  $nid = $node_path[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arg(1);
```

Is not a bad way of doing it. [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) works on the internal path, so it won't be affected by path aliases.

Comment: This is true, it won't be affected by path aliases.  But if you are on node/XXXXX, then you can just use $node->nid.  @French,  where else would you use arg(1) and it would return what you want?

Comment: if you are in a module hook you won't have access to node. Views arguments may be an example as well.

Comment: thanks jeremy and istryker, i have updated my question it might be clearer.. Though i ll try both of your solutions, thanks

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use arg() , you are binding yourself to a path, use `menu_get_object` (which just wraps around `menu_get_item` so that's equally good).

Comment: `if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)))` then `arg(1)` will to nearly 99% return you a node ID. But a solely `arg(1)` could also return you a lot of other IDs.