# Automatic Node Expire / Unpublish with Renew Option

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, rules

I have a classifieds site and would like to have a node expire after 45 days (unpublished), no matter how many times the user edits and saves the node. However after the node expires, the user has the ability to renew (publish) for another 45 days. I would like the time to be strictly 45 days with simple a renew button when it is expired.

Here is the workflow:

1. User creates node
2. Email is sent to node author indicating successful post.
3. Node is automatically expired 45 days later.
4. Email is sent to node author indicating expired post.
5. User has the ability to easily renew ad (expiry date is 45 days later yet again)
6. Email is sent to node author indicating renewed post (different from step 2)

I would also like to have a countdown for the days remaining until the expiry date.

I have successfully built steps 1-4 using rules only, however the rules are based on the event **'After saving new content'**, which means when a node is republished/renewed the rules do not follow because it is not new content.

I have also tried using the [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to set the unpublish date but cannot figure out how to enable renew only after it has expired.

I have also tried [Auto Expire](http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire) but I think it only gives the ability to renew before it expires, not after.

Comment: How the author renew the ad?

Comment: Maybe the author can renew the add by clicking a button on the node edit page, or a renew URL link can be sent to the email address.

Comment: for simplicity it is better done in hook_cron. To expire, just unpublish it.

Answer (score 0):

I would have opted for a custom code solution with the above work-flow.As an alternate contrib module option [classified Ads](https://drupal.org/project/ed_classified) module can be potential option.

Module Features:

> Renewable expired ads during the 'grace period' Simple taxonomy-based
>   browsing Ad expiration depending on category selection Per-user
>   classified ads lists – custom lists totally sortable Length-limited
>   body text with live counter of characters Advanced Help, CCK, Context,
>   Panels, Token and Views support

Answer (score -1):

This is an idea/suggested code but not solution. Use `node_save` to re-publish node.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
// set status property to 1
$node->status = 1;
// re-save the node
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a button and display it in menu local task tab (along with node `edit`).
2. Once the user clicked the "Renew" button it will trigger the custom function that contains something like monymirza's answer.

Make sure that the "Renew" button is only visible to node owner only.

```
function renewAd() {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  // set status property to 1
  $node->status = 1;
  // re-save the node
  node_save($node);
}
```

See this thread on how to get the nid from URL.

[Get a node ID from the URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6638/get-a-node-id-from-the-url)