# Accessing field inside a block

Tags: blocks, entities, database

I have created a block to display flash content. All it needs a a variable to be assigned dynamically from the content to flashVar. I created a field called myfile path in the custom content type. Which is just a text pointing to the path of file. I also created a block and below is the code inside the block.

```
<?php
$myFilePath = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_myfilepath');
?>

<script src="/player/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>
        function swfDimensions(width,height)
        {
           document.getElementById('altContent').style.width=width+'px';
           document.getElementById("altContent").style.height=height+'px';
        }
        var flashvars = {
                    filepath:"<?php echo $myFilePath;?>" // this where I use the filed value which my flash app uses internally

        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "",
            wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id:"altContent"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "/player/contentviewer.swf", 
            "altContent", "640px", "390px", "11.3.0",
            "/player/expressInstall.swf",
            flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
        <h4>Floorplan Basic</h1>

    <div id="altContent">
                To view this content you need Adobe flash player (v11+) plug-in installed on your browser
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Get Adobe Flash player</a></p>
    </div>
```

I am getting this error

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7663 of C:\...\www\includes\common.inc).
```

Can any on tell me how to get the value of the field in this block? I am totally new to drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `$node` is not defined. You should know [when a node page is shown](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6638/get-a-node-id-from-the-url). Then get the `node id` using `arg(1)`. Load the node object and then use.

Answer (score 0):

Try [variable_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)() and [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)()

Set the variable like that:

```
// I have assumed the variable name to be "the_name_of_the_variable"
variable_set("the_name_of_the_variable", "the value of the variable");
```

And then retrieve the value like that:

```
$my_variable = variable_get("the_name_of_the_variable", "a default value in case the variable has never been set before");
```