# How to use menu_get_object()?

Tags: nodes, 8

I was using `menu_get_object()` to load node information in Drupal 6.

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    // Get the nid
    $nid = $node->nid;
  }
```

Since `menu_get_object()` is deprecated in Drupal 8, I was using the following code.

```
if ($node_id = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) { #menu_get_object()   
    //load all the information of the node
    $node = node_load($node_id);
  }
  echo '<pre>';print_r($node);exit();echo '</pre>'; //its okay
  echo $node->type->value; //not working
```

This is not getting the node values, but printing the node information's in array. How do I resolve this ?

**UPDATE**

I am getting all other values like `$node->title->value` and `$node->nid->value`, but not `$node->type->value`.

Answer (score 7):

See
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202185/45409

In Drupal 8, you can get url arguments based on what's in the routing.

To get the id alone:

```
$nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
```

If you plan to load the node object, you can simply get it this way:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

To find the parameter names, you can use:

```
$possible_parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
```

To find the node type, use:

```
$node->bundle();
```

Comment: i actually need the values inside node object , when i use it like :   **$nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $node = node_load($nid);
  #echo '<pre>';print_r($node);exit(); echo '</pre>';
  echo $node->type->value;exit();** am getting all other values , but not **$node->type->value;**

Comment: try $node->bundle()

Comment: Also, try dump() in Drupal 8, instead of print_r, it's pretty nifty.

Comment: Also, avoid using node_load, it's deprecated, use \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

Comment: It would be $node->type->target_id, because it's an entity reference field. It's not always ->value. But either bundle() or getType() gives you the same information and is easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

`\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')` will return the node object, not the node id.

```
if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {   
  kint($node);
  echo $node->getType();    
}
```

Comment: kint($node) ??!

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getType() on string

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich kint() is for debugging in Drupal 8 and it comes with the devel module. You can also use print_r().

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich $node should be an object, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

If you compare what Drupal 7 does in [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) with what [Drupal 8 does in the same function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.2.x), you will see that the first function uses the following code.

```
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

The second function uses the following code.

```
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

[page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!page.html.twig/8.2.x) descrives `node` as follows:

> **node**: Fully loaded node, if there is an automatically-loaded node associated with the page and the node ID is the second argument in the page's path (e.g. node/12345 and node/12345/revisions, but not comment/reply/12345).

Also, `node_load()` should be replaced with the following code.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::load($nid);
```

You don't need `Node::load()` since `$variables['node']` already contains a full-loaded node object.

Comment: This actually does the same , i am getting all the details except type when try to access like **$node = Node::load($nid);cho $node->type->value;exit();**