# How to quickly tell what a URL maps to?

Tags: 7, uri

I'm in a new position working on an existing Drupal 7 site that I didn't help build. None of the original devs are here. Amongst other modules, the site makes uses of panels, panelizer, aliases, and redirects.

I get requests from marketing to update or change a page, and they include a URL. The URL is often an alias, but sometimes it can be a panels page, or a drupal entity "overriden" by panelizer.

Is there an easy way to see what exactly a URL maps to when I get a URL from marketing?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you running and are just wanting to know the node ID? If so, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6638/how-to-get-a-node-id-from-the-url and try `drupal_lookup_path()`.

Comment: @Christia a node ID is good, if I already know it's a node. But it could be a panels page or something panelized, like a taxonomy page. Drupal is obivously able to go through the appropriate objects to construct the page; I would like to tell me what it's doing so I can go to the object itself and start making changes.

Comment: Panel pages are still nodes but honestly, why don't you just go to the URL that marketing provides and edit it from there?

Comment: @Christia I go to the url that marketing provides and click "new draft" (forgot to mention, we also have workbench). The thing I need to change is not there. Since this is panelized, I click on "customize display". I find the field, and move it. But other nodes of the same kind have not changed. What I need to have done was go to the content type's "Full Page Override" and then "Content", to change all the content types.

Why do I have to play hide and seek just to change a page? Why can't drupal just tell me up front where the parts I need to change are stored?

Comment: With panels, that's the way you have do it. Drupal is a little different but you'll get used to it. :)  When you get used to that website, you can just go to structure > blocks or structure > views to find what you're looking for but what you're doing is still probably the easiest way. Edit: Deleted my comment so I could add to it.

Comment: @Christia Not used to it after 6 years. It's getting more than a little frustrating at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way. You have to have deep knowledge of the site's content to know how to edit what appears on the page. This is only obtained through poking around the site or asking a knowledgeable colleague.